# How can i get back the encoded value in a sql string?

Tags: sqlparameter

I have an email as follows:

```
    test+user1@test.com
```

Now when i make a call and pass it as a parameter i do the following

HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email)   in order to get the + sign.

But when i receive the email in the procedure , it is now

```
  test+user1%40test.com
```

I have tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode, but i no longer have the @ sign

and when i try to search my table , it cant find it.

My search is as follows:

"    SELECT  ......... where Email like   '%' + @Email + '%' ";

So how can i get it back to test+user1@test.com   ?

Comment: Maybe explain what problem you are trying to solve: Searching for an E-Mail address in an SQL database?